# Insert one string into another

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, youtube

I need to insert 'embed' into the middle of a YouTube URL, so e.g.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDCV_cK1L1A
```

Needs to be modified to:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=JDCV_cK1L1A
```

Using only jQuery.

Do I need to use RegEx for this? It seems the only answers I can find online are either appending / prepending, or inserting a string into `x` position of another string... but neither solution are appropriate for what I need to achieve

Comment: regex `(\/watch\?)` replacement string `embed$1`

Comment: jQuery is not required here. jQuery is best for DOM operations, native JS is best for string manipulation.

Comment: `url = url.replace(/(\.com\/)/, "$1embed/");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for this. If you want to add the folder right after the domain, you can use a plain `replace`:

```
url = url.replace('youtube.com/', 'youtube.com/embed/');
```

If you want to add it as the last folder, you can find the last slash and insert it there:

```
var last = url.lastIndexOf('/');
url = url.substr(0, last) + '/embed' + url.substr(last);
```